# Could not find setter for ID on class com.tct.model.Car

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring mvc and Hibernate with AliasToBeanResultTransformer. When I get data from jsp, I received an exception from SQL.

Model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CARS")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false, unique=true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME", length=50)
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
       return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
  }
```

This method get data from service:

```
public List<Car> getAllCars() {

    Session session = HibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory);
    String sqlQuery = GetSqlUtils.getSqlQueryString(CarRepositoryImpl.class, SQL_DIR + GET_ALL_CARS);
    List<Car> list = null;
    try {
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
        list = query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Car.class)).list();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.error("error at CarRepositoryImpl.getAllCars: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        HibernateUtils.closeCurrentSession(session);
    }       
    return list;            
}
```

SQL:

```
SELECT CAR.ID AS ID, CAR.NAME AS NAME 
     FROM 
        CARS CAR
```

Log message:

```
CarRepositoryImpl - error at CarRepositoryImpl.getAllCars: Could not find setter for ID on class com.tct.web.model.Car
```

How to fix this error ? thank so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields are declared in lowercase and you use uppercase aliases.

Try to change them so they are exactly as the field names:

```
SELECT CAR.ID AS id, CAR.NAME AS name
```

Comment: Hi @Maciej Kowalski: it worked, this is my base error, I hope your help will useful for me or someone, thank so much !!

Comment: Great! Glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

change `int` to `Integer` for id

```
private Integer id;
public Integer getId() {
   return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
   this.id = id;
}
```